# What does "traversed" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I looked "beat" up in Merriam-Webster dictionary. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beat

Entry 2 Sense 7 b: one of the reaches (see REACH entry 2 sense 1) in the zigzag course so traversed : TACK

What does the "so traversed" mean here? Is traversed an adjective? But the dictionary shows "traversed" is the past tense of traverse, not an adjective.

Comment: Past tense verb forms are often used adjectivally - ***beaten** egg* or [*a **well-traveled** path,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22well-traveled+path%22) for example.  And in your context, ***traversed*** is just an alternative to ***traveled, crossed, followed,*** or similar. The M-W cite doesn't give enough context to say *exactly* what ***so** traversed* refers back to, but basically it just means *traversed / crossed **in that way*** (we just don't know ***which*** way).

Comment: It doesn't bear on the meaning of "traversed" but I expect that the definition is talking about sailing - specifically sailing to windward (aka beating to windward). Every beat involves traversing some water.

Comment: @KannE I sail a parallel course to you and feel that you deserve to edit and promote your comment to an answer, or indeed, *the* answer.

Comment: Note that *traversing* carries no particular implication of *[nautical] tacking, zigzagging, "weaving"*. It just means to move / travel / pass ***through / across*** some "area".

Comment: @KannE Re-reading after several months I still think you deserve to upgrade to an answer. Thanks.